# Need help with shared folder on ubuntu vm

Tags: server, virtualbox

I am using Try Ubuntu on a VM, I have not installed it yet as I'm not sure it will work for me.

I created a shared folder in the VM shared folder- in my windows C:\Users\sfox\documents\images with Access Full AutoMount Yes at /srv/tftp

I put 2 or 3 files in the images folder on my Windows PC but when I type ls -lah /srv/tftp on the VM I don't see any files.

I rebooted the VM after setting the shared folder and I use the following commands each time I start up the VM:

```
sudo apt install net-tools
sudo apt -y install tftp-server
sudo systemctl start tftpd-hpa
```